# Presenting the UIActivityViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Does anyone know how I can show an activity view in Swift, in Objective-C I know it would be something like this, but I can't figure it out in Swift

```
NSArray *ActItems;

ActItems = @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"my text"]];

UIActivityViewController *actviewcon = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:ActItems applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:actviewcon animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: What code have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: Why are you calling `stringWithFormat:` to create a literal string?  Why are you sending `nil` to one method and `NULL` to the other when you should be sending `nil` to both?

Comment: @nhgrif While the provided code leaves a lot to be desired, the nil/null usage here matches apple's documentation. Regarding the UIActivityViewController's applicationActivities parameter, Apple says "This parameter may be nil.", whereas the completion in the presentViewController method should be "A completion handler or NULL."

Comment: @nhgrif i found this code on SO a while ago and didnt really check through it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below does what your objective-c code above does.

```
let firstActivityItem = "my text"
let activityViewController : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivityItem], applicationActivities: nil)
self.navigationController.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Am i missing something? This just presents a full screen modal view with the text "No share actions available". This is not how it looks in iOS7. What am i missing? I'm using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like in Swift.

```
let activityItems = ["Cool stuff to share!"]
let actviewcon = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)

self.presentViewController(actviewcon, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Additionally, there's no need to use a formatted string if you aren't inserting any variable information into it. You're better of just using a string literal.

Comment: Am i missing something? This just presents a full screen modal view with the text "No share actions available". This is not how it looks in iOS7. What am i missing? I'm using the simulator.

Comment: @Spoek Couldn't tell you, but this code works fine. Try a real device, it doesn't really matter if it works on the simulator.